# Limit NSTextView to digits only

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

How can I limit a NSTextView to digits only? NSFormatter isn't available for NSTextView, and I couldn't find any options on the NSTextStorage/NSTextContainer either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `NSTextView` and override

```
- (void)insertText:(id)string replacementRange:(NSRange)replacementRange
```

Strip the non-digits from `string` and call super.

Override

```
- (BOOL)readSelectionFromPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard type:(NSString *)type
```

to catch paste and drop.

Answer (score 0):

You could respond to the delegate method

`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` and then check if what is typed is a digit (use a characterSet for this). If it is a digit, return YES; if not, return NO.

Or maybe change the keyboard type to digits only.

Comment: This breaks copy&paste, as opposed to the experience with a formatter where you can replace with a normalised string.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after posting the answer that it may not work with Copy&Paste.